# Ionic events not working correctly between lazy-loaded modules

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, events, ionic3, dom-events

As I've created an ionic app, with basic lazy-loading implementation. Suppose for the sake of an example, my app contains 2 ***lazy-loaded*** pages, **Page1** & **Page2**

So in the constructor of ***`page1.ts`*** I've published an event named **`hello`**, and inside the constructor of ***`page2.ts`***, I've subscribed to that particular event.

My app starts with `Page1`.

But after running up the app, I found that my event isn't been subscribed on publishing the event `hello` directly from the constructor of `Page1`. Can you please help me out with this, that why my subscribe method (inside `Page2` constructor) isn't listening to the published event from `Page1`.

Sample Code:

**page1.ts** (app starts with this)

```
constructor(public events: Events) {
    this.events.publish('hello', 'some data');
    console.log('Published');
}
```

**page2.ts**

```
constructor(public events: Events) {
    this.events.subscribe('hello', (data) => {
        // This isn't working in case of lazy-loading
        console.log('subscribed to hello with data', data);
    });
}
```

As soon as my app starts, only `Published` logs into the console. and nothing happens after that. But according to my understanding of ionic events, the subscribe method of `Page2` should also work after publishing of that event. Isn't it? Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your Page2 is *lazy loaded* so it hasn't been created yet.

Ionic Events creates a list for each event you publish.This contains a list of callbacks where your callback function is added whenever you subscribe to the event. When the event is published the callbacks present in the list are called.

When you publish in page 1, if your page 2 has not been loaded, the callback will not be called as it isnt in the list at the time.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer, I was also thinking of this only. So, do you mean that in the implementation of lazy-loading its impossible to do the task which I'm trying to do? Is there any way around to it so that I can achieve that without removing lazy-loading?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do in page2 component on subscribe..you could subscribe in a singleton provider

Comment: Ok, singleton would do that for me. Thanks for the help! But does ionic's or angular's dependency intejction `@Injector` supports singleton initializations?

Comment: Yes, but No in your case. If you include it in the main app module and don't lazy load stuff. If you inject something from a lazy loaded page, it won't be a singleton because lazy loading starts up its own separate Dependency Injector. Yeah I know :( You probably want to maintain a regular class Globals and just manage states there. When you lazy-load your page, check on the states. To manage globals, subscribe to stuff at the core module level.

Comment: @DmitriR117 Thanks for the reply. Can you please show me some example somewhere so that I can understand the way you're talking about more better!

Comment: @SurajRao Can you give me some working example of the technique of implementing it using singleton way?

Answer (score -1):

You have to run `subscribe` method before your event is published.
 It is like a TV show. The subscriber is your TV. The publisher is the show. You need to turn on your TV before the show presenting or you will miss it.